# Lubuntu 18.04.2 LTS has upgraded to kernel 5.0.0.23 via Software Update

Tags: kernel, lubuntu

My installation of Lubuntu 18.04.2 LTS has upgraded to kernel 5.0.0.23 from 4.18.0-25 via Software Update and my Airspy HF+ SDR is no longer recognised. I can get GQRX to recognise it by reverting to the older kernel version. I have seen a comment in ask ubuntu that suggests 18.04 should not be using version 5.0.0.23. Is this upgrade correct?

Comment: 5.0.0.23 is the HWE kernel for Ubuntu and flavors LTS 18.04.3.  The bump of the dot-number to .3 should come soon.  You might want to [edit] your question to have an actual question in it, right now it reads like a comment.

Comment: If you want non-HWE kernels you should install either Lubuntu 18.04 or Lubuntu 18.04.1.  All ISO's from .2 onwards have HWE enabled by default (*I, along with others are in the process of QA-testing the .3 ISO currently, it should be released Thursday*).  You can `apt full-upgrade` either 18.04/18.04.1 or 18.04.2 after installation and they end up the same, except for kernel being used; 18.04.2 using HWE kernel (which will upgrade itself until it finally uses the 20.04 kernel). Your behavior is consistent with a 18.04.2 installation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want non-HWE kernels you should install either Lubuntu 18.04 or Lubuntu 18.04.1. All ISO's from .2 onwards have HWE enabled by default (*I, along with others are in the process of QA-testing the .3 ISO currently, it should be released Thursday 8 August 2019 though will use the HWE kernel too*).

You can `sudo apt full-upgrade` either 18.04/18.04.1 or 18.04.2 after installation and they end up the same, except for kernel being used; 18.04.2 using HWE kernel (which will upgrade itself until it finally uses the 20.04 kernel).

Your behavior is consistent with a 18.04.2 installation

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack for details about the HWE or hardware enablement stack kernels.  HWE kernels whilst in theory are slightly less stable (less production testing), they have advantages for newer hardware...